# file handler is not printing after writing in to file in python

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to write one file and read after writing. Below is my code.

```
with open('1.txt','w') as fr:
    x = '3'
    fr.write(x)
    with open('1.txt','r') as fr_r:
        fr_w = fr_r.read()
        print (fr_w)
```

expected output is below

3

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: it won't be correct to play with same file pointer (initialized each time) in different nested contexts

Comment: Indent your read code to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should read (without indentation for the second with)

```py
with open('1.txt','w') as fr:
    x = '3'
    fr.write(x)
with open('1.txt','r') as fr_r:
    fr_w = fr_r.read()
    print (fr_w)
```

Answer (score 1):

once YOu opend a file with 'with' statement . you no need to close that channel . for that reason python developers has set a restriction to not to write or use  a another  permission channel in this block .

```
                   once read /write permission in opened we cannot add another permission channel in that block or indentation. it should be in seperate indentation like this below as follows``
```